# Laravel - 403 Error with Load Balancer and Email verification

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

We send a verification link via the Laravel email verification.
A 403 error occurred frequently when the user clicked on the verification link. But the error did not always occur, for some users the link worked, for others it did not.

We use a Laravel Forge load balancer to distribute the load evenly between two of our app servers. We then found out that the APP_KEY values of the two app servers we were using did not match. We fixed that, additionally we increased the validity period of the verification link from 5 minutes to 24 hours.

What we already tried (after some stack overflow research):

- `APP_KEY` in the ENV set the same for both servers
- Increased the validity period for the links from 5 minutes to 24 hours
- in `TrustProxies`, `$proxies` set to the IPs of the load balancers
- in `TrustProxies`, `$proxies` set to `'*'`
- Paused one of the servers in the loadbalancer

However, the problem still occurs and we are at a bit of a loss as to what else it could be.

Comment: Hey, stumbled on that problem also, been like two weeks. I just realized I wasn't using the `\App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class` in the middlewareGroups array in `App\Http\Kernel.php` file. This fixed my problem.